# carbonating with beer gas or c02

Tags: carbonation, fermentation-temperature, help

Question can you carbonate a stout with c02 and then pour it on beer gas(nitrogen) and have the same cascading effect? Or do I have to carbonate with the beer has only

Comment: Sorry I got that - by mistake I am new here dodnt know what I was doing your answer was very helpful

Comment: I would advise you click to delete this question since the other one is more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

No you should carbonate with c02 only to about 2 volumes as nitro systems instruct.
Then serve on beer gas using a higher than normal pressure than you would pure c02, up to 25psi.

Comment: So carb with c02 the stout 2nd pour on beer gas got it cheers